How to authenticate on Keycloak admin console in a Node.js app?
I am making a platform which has Keycloak integrated for user authentication. Right now I need to get a list of all the client roles from a specific client. To do this, I have to login into the admin console, but with what I am trying, I am getting ngnix 502 Bad Gateway error.
This is the endpoint I am working on. It is supposed to first get all of the client roles of the clientENV client, then it iterates those roles to return the list of each user with the specific role.
app.get('/showClientUsers', async (req, res) => {
  const clientId = clientENV;

  const kcAdminClient = new KcAdminClient({
      authServerURLENV,
      realmName: realmENV
  });

  try {
      await kcAdminClient.auth({
          username: userENV,
          password: secretKeycloakENV,
          grantType: 'password',
          clientId: 'admin-cli'
      });

      kcAdminClient.setConfig({ realmName: realmENV });

      const clients = await kcAdminClient.clients.find({ clientId });
      if (clients.length === 0) {
          return res.status(404).send('Client not found.');
      }

      const client = clients[0];
      const roles = await kcAdminClient.clients.listRoles({ id: client.id });
      const allUsers = [];

      for (const role of roles) {
          const usersInRole = await kcAdminClient.clients.findUsersWithRole({
              id: client.id,
              roleName: role.name
          });

          usersInRole.forEach(user => {
              allUsers.push({ username: user.username, role: role.name });
          });
      }

      res.json(allUsers);
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch users:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Failed to fetch users');
  }
});

However, when I try to call the endpoint it gives me a 502 response and I can't seem to figure it out.
